# Sending a React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>> as a prop to another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm attempting to import a React functionComponent from an SVG and then send that to another component as a prop to render that svg. With the setup below, this compiles fine, but eventually crashes when trying to render the svg in browser with:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Classes below are simplified. But the gist of what I'm trying to do is:

In overlay.tsx:

```
import { ReactComponent as icon } from "/icon.svg";
import CustomItem from "/customItem";

const Overlay: React.FC<OverlayProps> = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <CustomItem icon={icon}/>
        </div>
    );
    export default Overlay;
}
```

and in customItem.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

export interface CustomItemProps {
    icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
}

const CustomItem: React.FC<CustomItemProps> = ({icon}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {icon}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ApplicationsDropdownItem;
```

I assume my problem is somewhere around the syntax of {icon}, but I can not for the life of me find out what I'm suppose to use instead.

Comment: importing the svg location as a string and painting it with <img src={icon}/> does work, however that eliminates all css possibilities that comes with using svg as a component.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer

The icon you are importing is a component, therefore it must be called to render the JSX.

`<Icon {...props}/>` (correct) or `{Icon(props)}` (not recomended)

Since it is a component, you should also name it `Icon` and not `icon`.

Take a look at [this blog post](https://blog.sapegin.me/til/react/generating-typescript-react-components-from-svg-icons-using-svgr/) that explains SVGR.

#### TL;DR - Best approach for rendering components

A. Call the component in your render method with component syntax `<MyComponent/>` not `MyComponent()`.

B. Instantiate your component as a variable, and pass that to your render method's JSX block.

#### More info

@DustInCompetent brought to light the issue of calling a component as a function inside a JSX block.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67185279/943773) and [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component), that will lead to react not registering a components hooks and lead to state and other problems.

If you are implementing a High Level Component ([HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method)), then you should not call a component [within the render method](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method) (return statement in functional components), as this leads to problems for similar registration issues of the component.

Comment: I read the `{fnComp(props)}` form is discouraged as it messes with event propagation and React dev tools or something

Comment: I also think that stylistically it is ugly and confusing, and I rarely see that used; though, it is possible. I'll update my example to clarify that. If you find/recall the resource that mentioned this, it would be great to add that here.

Comment: I think I found it: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method. It's about HOCs but the same applies to calling a function that returns a new component tree on every render.

Comment: That's very interesting. I understand that to mean that the component should rather be instantiated outside of the render/return statement of a component. Not necessarily that function syntax should not be used in a JSX block. But not sure.

Comment: Just googled and found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67185279/943773), which led me to [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component) that explains React cannot register a component's hooks when components are called as functions in JSX.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as SampleIcon } from "/sample_icon.svg";

export interface CustomItemProps {
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
}

const CustomItem: React.FC<CustomItemProps> = (props) => {
  const Temp = props.Icon as React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  return (
    <div>
      <Temp/>
    </div>
  );
};

<CustomItem Icon={SampleIcon}/>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer with some description so that it brings more context. Code-only answers are hard to read and understand. Thanks

Comment: this answered my question of how to name/call the function component:
const Temp = props.Icon as React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
...
<Temp/>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `<Icon />` instead of `{icon}` because it's a component.

Comment: That will not work. It does not understand where to get said component from

Comment: @Excludos Literally assign `const Icon = props.icon` and use it as a component. It's already of type FunctionComponent, you just need to use it as such.